# Was this part of roof and eaves done right?

Tags: roof

Look in pictures below. This section of roof was open before and we asked if it could be covered.  We are getting a new roof and roofer said no problem and this was his solution.  However, his roofers made the eaves uneven, they don't match up.  I don't know how this is going to work with the gutters we are having installed next.  It has taken the company a full week, even the weekend, to do this roofing job. Was it done right?  Would you be happy with this?  Is it normal to have an eave hang lower? How would you fix this and would you pay this guy?  My husband thinks it's fine, but he has found other problems with the roof as well.  I think it's shoddy work.  Should I make a complaint to bbb?  Contractor only came first day of work to see roofers working. Thank you for any input.

[image][image]

Comment: It looks awful to me - but I'm just an amateur diy'er... If I were doing that myself I'd certainly have tried to find a better way.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I'm not crazy in thinking it looks terrible. My husband thinks it looks fine. I think he's saying that because he hired the guy.

Comment: I am a retired general building contractor and this crap is amature and unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you shirlock! I agree. I appreciate your expert opinion:)

Answer (score 3):

The height of the fascia (the vertical face at the edge of the roof) depends on 3 parameters: Overhang depth, truss (rafter) heel height, and roof pitch (slope).

If any of these things vary from one plane to another, at least one of the other parameters must be adjusted to accommodate. It's often simplest to have a slight variation in overhang depth. It's hard to say what impact that would have on your home from the photos provided. Judging by the fairly low slope you'd lose 6-12" of overhang to bring the fascias into alignment.

If you didn't work those things out with your contractor beforehand you may not have much recourse at this point. There is no violation of contract, and it's merely an aesthetic issue. If you're on good terms, discuss making a change and split the cost if the contractor doesn't agree that it was a mistake.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't ask about the eaves being done uneven because I didn't even think that would be an issue. They were even before. I'll ask the contractor what can be done.

Comment: From my point of view, it looks like two options to fix this. First, cut the eave gradually so it matches the other, and then it's crooked on that end. Or, cut the end of the lower eave at a forty five degree angle, and hope the gutters cover it. Do you have any other ideas? I'm just trying to think of ways to fix this. Thanks again! I appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you rejecting my suggestion that the roof overhang be shortened? That's the only 'right' solution, in my book. If there's a reason to not do that, let it be known.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry if my writing came across the wrong way, I didn't mean to. I'm not rejecting your suggestion, I sincerely appreciate your time and help. That's a great idea! I'm going to suggest this to the contractor.

Comment: I wasn't asking because I was insulted, but because I'l like to see you arrive at a satisfactory resolution. The suggestions in your second comment here were not ideal fixes, in my book.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah...that's completely unacceptable and not professional. In terms of how to fix it, I'd have to know how it was done and why it wound up that way. I suspect just poor measurement and layout from the overall appearance. Is it a breach of contract? No one here can answer that without reading it but there are generally accepted standards of workmanship and that isn't.

As far as what to do, that's hard for any of us to answer. I'd speak to the GC and tell him it's just not acceptable and put it in his lap. A lot depends on what state you're in. Some have very strong protection for customers of contractors, some very little.

But the bottom line is I wouldn't accept it or ask a customer to.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think it's professional either. I will ask the contractor why it wound up that way. Generally accepted standards would be that the eaves would be lined up, right? I don't get why he wouldn't have talked with us beforehand. If he would have, I would have said to leave the 4 ft. opening that was there instead of covering it. At least the eaves matched before. It seems like we're stuck with it and we were not told by the contractor it was going to be uneven. We're in California. He does have his license. I looked up the name on his workers' truck and it has 2 complaints on bbb.

Comment: The name is different than his business. He said the one on the truck is his brother's business. Obviously, he has his brother and his workers doing this job. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How would you resolve this? Is there anything I can do, or is it too late? If I was to get someone to give me ideas on how to make this look acceptable, what type of person should I call, another contractor?

Comment: The contractor is coming at the end of today to get his money.

Comment: Part One ;)
Yes, the eaves should line up or there should have been a discussion as to how to handle it beforehand.  I don't place a lot of weight on the BBB but the whole different names thing is a red flag that he is unable to do business under his own name.  I was a licensed contractor in CT, so I don't know the law in CA, although my recollection is that they have a reputation for being tough on shady contractors.  Personally, I would tell him it's unacceptable and that you won't pay the balance until a mutually acceptable solution is agreed upon... and completed.

Comment: Part Two @Teach
If there's much money involved the typical response (if you had a written contract) would be for him to file a Mechanic's Lien as a scare tactic as much as anything else.  But I would suggest the best course of action to be stress that you are willing and prepared to pay the balance once (and only once) he completes the job in a "workmanlike" fashion...
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Paul! If he can't think of any solution, I will suggest the ones given here. I don't even do this job for a living and could easily tell it wasn't done right. There are other things too,,, not installing three roof vents, improperly installing one, not nailing the eaves together on the house, etc. Hundreds of roofing nails are also poking out under the eaves and the painter asked why. He said they'll still show after he paints. The contractor told me the nail thing is normal. I will use your suggestions! Thank you for the good luck! I'll need it:)

Comment: The "nail thing" is not normal. We call them shiners and it happened because the roofer was too lazy/cheap to go find shorter roofing nails. It is unprofessional. They make them as short as 1/2" so don't let him tell you they aren't made.

Comment: Roofing nails are supposed (required?) to penetrate completely through the roof decking and show 1/8" unless it's *more than* 3/4" thick. You typically can't use nails that don't show through. This is why soffits were invented. In my world, "shiners" are nail heads that show below the bottom edge of the overlaid shingle.